# Connecting from GCP to AWS instances behind VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, vpn

I am trying to find a simple solution to the following problem. I have 2 microservices in AWS behind VPN on machines with a static IP (which won't change) behind VPN (so it's visible by another AWS instances in the same security group) and then I have another microservice on GCP (Kubernetes), which needs to access these (basically for aa very simple and very occasional HTTP POST requests). What would be the easiest way to do so? I was thinking about specifying IP addresses of my Kubernetes pool instances to inbound rules in the AWS security group for those two microservices, but that is dangerous because of the dynamic nature of these...

I found some solutions using [tunnels](https://medium.com/google-cloud/vpn-between-two-clouds-e2e3578be773) and cetera, but most of the guides were either outdated or doesn't suite to my needs. They e.g. require to create a new VPC, while I want to reuse the existing one. I am sure it's the way, but seems as a huge overkill to me. Couldn't I e.g. somehow leverage Ingress or some simple proxy container?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered  a pub/sub model, or is that too high latency for these requests?

Comment: Sorry, what does it mean in reality for this usecase?

Comment: Just proposing a possible alternative if you are unable to satisfactorily resolve the connection difficulties. You're trying to connect the producers of messages to the consumers of those messages. Pub/Sub is one potential solution, where the producers and consumers are loosely coupled.

Comment: I found out that two proxies solution is probably sufficient for my needs. But thank you for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using [two proxies](http://danielhnyk.cz/connecting-from-gcp-to-aws-services/).